# How to derive OLS estimator?

Tags: econometrics

$y_t = B_0 + B_1t$

I have proved $B_0 = \bar{y} - B_1t$

I have found $B_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T t \cdot (y_t - \bar{y})} {\sum_{t=1}^T t \cdot (t - \bar{t})} $

However I'm supposed to have $B_1 = \frac{ \sum_{t=1}^T y_t \cdot (t - \bar{t})} {\sum_{t=1}^T t \cdot (t - \bar{t})} $

Was just wondering if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you want to write $\bar{y}$?  The tex command for this is \bar{y}.

Comment: Yes I did, thank you!

Comment: Is your initial equation: yt=B0−B1t or should it be a "+" sign? Since your desired estimation formula is that of yt = B0 +B1t

Comment: You are already correct. The second equation for $B_1$ is incorrect.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=derive+ols+estimator&oq=derive+OLS+estimator&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.2615j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_3z2yXtq-G5mtytMPuOed2Ag42     would this link help?

Comment: They are equal: $\sum_{t=1}^T (a_t-\bar{a})b_t = \sum_{t=1}^T a_t (b_t-\bar{b}) = \sum_{t=1}^T (a_t-\bar{a})(b_t-\bar{b})$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!